# Converting PHP to ERB in Ruby on Rails

Tags: php, ruby-on-rails, xml, xslt, erb

I'm new to Ruby on Rails and I have some code in PHP that will transform my xml document with my xsl document on my browser.
I need some up help converting the code to erb.

```
  <?php
      // Load XML file
      $xml = new DOMDocument;
      $xml->load('famousQoutes.xml');

      // Load XSL file
      $xsl = new DOMDocument;
      $xsl->load('famousQ.xsl');

     // Configure the transformer
     $proc = new XSLTProcessor;

     // Attach the xsl rules
     $proc->importStyleSheet($xsl);

     echo $proc->transformToXML($xml);
    ?>
```

Any help is much appreciated, thanks in advance.

Comment: Your question looks little vague to me but i would suggest you should try this gem: https://github.com/roo-rb/roo, I think there is too little of `erb` involved here.

Comment: Thanks, but my I'm want to display an XML document that's formatted with XSLT and use ERB or a gem to display it.(I hope that clears things up) The roo gem is for spreadsheets. Thanks anyway

Comment: I don't know if I get your question, but maybe [this gem](https://github.com/glejeune/ruby-xslt) can help. I never use it. Just did a research.

Comment: You can use XML builder in Ruby on rails. Example is given in the link https://richonrails.com/articles/outputting-xml-using-ruby-on-rails. See the last snippet

Comment: Thanks, everyone for your help I'll try your solutions